# Retrieving urls using mutiple search words in csv file from google search. The csv file is empty when i run the above code

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a list of companies in csv columns for which I don't have URLs. I would like to search google and add the URLs of each company to csv file. I would like to Google search only the exact company name.
Lists = companiesnames.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import urllib

with open("database.csv", "r", newline="") as f_input:
csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=";", quotechar="|")
    lists = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]   

with open("results.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=";")

for list in lists: 
        search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?&q={}".format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(list, safe='/'))
        google = requests.get(search_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(google.content, "html.parser")

for r in soup.find_all('a', class_='r'):
                csv_writer.writerow([list, r.a.text, r.a['href'][7:]])
```

Lists = [Accolade wines, Da loc, New viet dairy,..]

Comment: Welcome to SO! So, what exactly is your problem? Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then use the 'edit' function to provide some more details.

Comment: The csv file is empty when i run the above code. I do not get the required results.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't specified a `user-agent`. Learn more about [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) and HTTP request [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Basically, `user-agent` let identifies the browser, its version number, and its host operating system that representing a person (browser) in a Web context that lets servers and network peers identify if it's a bot or not.

In short, you need to send a fake `user-agent` so Google would treat your request as a "real" user visit otherwise, it will block a request eventually and you'll receive a completely different HTML that contains an error message with completely different selectors and elements. [Check what is your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent` in `headers`:

```
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get(YOUR_URL, headers=headers)
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Answer-Box-Age-and-write-to-csv#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, csv

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

company_list = ['facebook', 'whatsapp', 'alibaba', 'sony']

# declare a csv file name
with open('companies_file.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:

  # creating column headers
  fieldnames = ['Company name', 'Company URL']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

  # adding column headers
  writer.writeheader()

  company_data = []
  
  # iterating over company names
  for company in company_list:
    html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={company}&hl=en&gl=us', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    
    comapny_url = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']

    print(f'Writing data from {company} company.')
    
    # adding data to the array as a dict() so csv.writer can write to csv file
    # Values should be the same as in the fieldnames variable
    company_data.append({
      'Company name': company,
      'Company URL': comapny_url
    })

  # iterate over each entry and write to csv file
  for data in company_data:
    writer.writerow(data)

-----------
'''
Writing data from facebook company.
...

# CSV output:
Company name,Company URL
facebook,https://www.facebook.com/
whatsapp,https://www.whatsapp.com/?lang=en
alibaba,https://www.alibaba.com/
sony,https://www.sony.com/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that everything is already done for the end-user and the only thing that needs to be done on your part is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want, rather than figuring out what things don't work as they should.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, csv

company_list = ['facebook', 'whatsapp', 'alibaba', 'sony']

with open('serpapi_companies_solution.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
  fieldnames = ['Company name', 'Company URL']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  writer.writeheader()

  company_data = []

  for company in company_list:
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "google_domain": "google.com",
      "q": f"{company}",
      "hl": "en",
      "gl": "us"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    print(f"Writing data from {company} company.")

    company_url = results["organic_results"][0]["link"]

    company_data.append({
      "Company name": company,
      "Company URL": company_url
    })

  for data in company_data:
    writer.writerow(data)

--------------
'''
Writing data from facebook company.
Writing data from whatsapp company.
...

# output from CSV:
Company name,Company URL
facebook,https://www.facebook.com/
whatsapp,https://www.whatsapp.com/?lang=en
alibaba,https://www.alibaba.com/
sony,https://www.sony.com/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.